# StreamContent doesn't take the length of the stream

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, filestream

I am interacting with dropbox and I get a file by it's path, read it out as a stream, copy the content of that stream into a filestream and use that filestream to make a StreamContent object which I can append to my multipart/form-data:

```cs
[FunctionName("SendFiles")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
{
    ...
    DropboxClient dropbox = new DropboxClient("token");

    MultipartFormDataContent formdata = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    string name = GetFileName(filePath);
    string tempfile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    string tempFilePath = getTempFilePath(tempfile, name);
    FileStream fs = File.Create(tempFilePath);
    using (var res = await dropbox.Files.DownloadAsync(filePath))
    {
          (await res.GetContentAsStreamAsync()).CopyTo(fs);
    }

    HttpContent content = new StreamContent(fs);

    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", GetFileType(name));
    formdata.Add(content, "files", name);
    // System.IO.File.Delete(tempfile); at this point, we still are using the file for some reason and so I can't delete it
    // rest of the method, sending the content using httpClient
...
}

private static string getTempFilePath(string tempfile, string name)
{
    char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '\\' };
    var splitPath = tempfile.Split(charSeparators);
    splitPath[splitPath.Length - 1] = name;
    return String.Join("\\", splitPath);
}

private static string GetFileName(string path)
{
    char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '/' };
    var splitPath = path.Split(charSeparators);
    return splitPath[splitPath.Length - 1];
}

private static string GetFileType(string name)
{
    char[] charSeparators = new char[] { '.' };
    var splitName = name.Split(charSeparators);
    string extension = splitName[1].ToLower();
    switch (extension)
    {
        case "pdf":
              return "application/pdf";
        case "png":
              return "image/png";
        case "doc":
              return "application/msword";
        case "docx":
              return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        case "txt":
             return "text/plain";
        case "tif":
             return "image/tif";
        case "jpg":
            return "image/jpg";
        case "rtf":
            return "application/rtf";
        // default == not supported type, we don't set content type
        default:
            return "";
     }
}
```

When I'm debugging, I can clearly see that the length of the stream gets updated when copying to the filestream but when I then use the filestream to create the stream content, the content's length remains 0. How is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks like you are using Azure Functions here, so writing to disk is not guaranteed that it will work and is not recommended. Why not write to a memory stream instead or simply feed the stream from dropbox into StreamContent()? it looks like the issue here is that the filesystem stream is at the end of the stream when you pass it into StreamContent(), so look at Seek on the streams.

Comment: You're right, I can just directly feed that stream into the content and it works! thanks a lot!

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt if you can write this comment out as an answer, I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to feed the stream from the dropbox client directly into the StreamContent like this:

```
HttpContent content = new StreamContent(await res.GetContentAsStreamAsync());
```